# Pull a random grandchild link of a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type(comics) that I am attempting to pull a random grandchild for(random button in navigation).  THis custom post type is arranged in three levels

_ Comic Title

__ Chapter Title

___ Comic Page

I've written the following

```
    $argsComics = array( 
        'post_type' => 'comics',
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $titles = get_posts( $argsComics ); 

    $argsIssues = array( 
        'post_type' => 'comics',
        'post_parent__in' => $titles,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    
    $issues = get_posts( $argsIssues ); 
    
    $argsPages = array( 
        'post_type' => 'comics',
        'post_parent__in' => $issues,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );

    $random_comic = get_posts( $argsPages );
    
    $random = array_rand($random_comic);

    $random_post_url = get_permalink($random);
```

and I'm getting completely random permalinks.  What am I doing wrong? There should be a simplier way of getting a random link that does just all grandchildren in this post type.

Comment: _"that I am attempting to pull a random grandchild for"_ - a random grandchild of the _current_ top-level post, or _any_ top-level posts? Either way, I don't see any relevant limitation of the selection in your first query (it does not limit the selection to one specific post, or even posts that are top-level.)

Answer (score 1):

from the wordpress [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) the `get_posts()` returns an array of post objects ; and you have to provide an array of parent's post ids (not array of objects) to `get_posts()` for `post_parent__in` argument.

so using php function `array_column()` will fix your problem.
like this:

```php
$argsComics = array(
    'post_type' => 'comics',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$titles = get_posts( $argsComics );

$argsIssues = array(
    'post_type' => 'comics',
    'post_parent__in' => array_column($titles,'id'),
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$issues = get_posts( $argsIssues );

$argsPages = array(
    'post_type' => 'comics',
    'post_parent__in' => array_column($issues,'id'),
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

$random_comic = get_posts( $argsPages );

$random = array_rand($random_comic);

$random_post_url = get_permalink($random);
```

Comment: also getting all of the posts by using `'posts_per_page' => -1` for multiple times impacts your performance and server's resource usage.